# How to get liveBroadcast Schedule time using channel ID

Tags: api, youtube

I am working with youtube data api and trying to get Live Broadcast schedule time not publish time.
Example
Apr 10, 2022
Scheduled[For more details image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqH7Q.png)

Please answer the relative answer if you know your answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with the YouTube Data API.

You could use the "search" endpoint for retrieve the "upcoming" videos from a given channel - [see example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCgdpiakw3lGkW27tSwptAow%22%2C%22eventType%22%3A%22upcoming%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D) - and then use another tool for extract (*i.e. web scraping*) the videos obtained from the previous search request for get the values "scheduledStartTime" and "startTimestamp" in the embed javascript code - both contains the scheduled time in UNIX and Date Time value respectively.

Also, check in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) if there is an official response.